# As.numeric function with binary data in R

Tags: r

I recently encountered a new problem in R which I did not see before. I have a set of data with a dependent variable Accuracy which has only two values, "0" and "1". Before, I use data$Accuracy=as.numeric(data$Accuracy) to turn these two levels to numbers and it works.

This time, however, when I did the same thing. "0"s turned to "1"s and "1"s turned to "2"s. Is this due to the new changes made in R? How do I work around this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the columns are `factor` class and when we use `as.numeric`, we get the integer storage mode values (in R, indexing starts from 1).  In that case, we can convert to `character` and then to `numeric`

```
data$Accuracy <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Accuracy))
```

Comment: This is my guess too.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a factor the *manual recommends*

```
as.numeric(levels(data$Accuracy))[data$Accuracy]
```

to transform it to approximately its original numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there could be a problem with the dataframe definition or reading from a file. If original data where only 0 and 1 data$Accuracy should be class integer. But any no numeric character in just one row will create a factor column. As example:

```
> zz<-data.frame(c(0, 0, 1, 1))
> zz
  c.0..0..1..1.
1             0
2             0
3             1
4             1
> zz<-data.frame(c(0, 0, 1, 1, "")) # an empty space
> zz
  c.0..0..1..1.....
1                 0
2                 0
3                 1
4                 1
5                  
> class(zz$c.0..0..1..1.....)
[1] "factor"
> zz<-data.frame(c(0, 0, 1, 1, NA)) # empty numeric data
> zz
  c.0..0..1..1..NA.
1                 0
2                 0
3                 1
4                 1
5                NA
> class(zz$c.0..0..1..1..NA.)
[1] "numeric"
```